# Return value from row based on column value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a data frame that has a column of lists of strings, I want to find the value of a colum in a row which is based on the value of another column

i.e

```
         samples  subject  trial_num
0    ['aa','bb']        1          1
1    ['bb','cc']        1          2
```

I have ['bb','cc'] and I want to get the value from the trial_num column where this list equals the samples colum, in this case 2.

Answer (score 1):

Given the search column (`samples`) contains a list, it makes thing a tiny bit more complicated.

In this case, the `apply()` function can be used to test the values, and return a boolean mask, which can be applied to the DataFrame to obtain the required value.

Example code:

```
df.loc[df['samples'].apply(lambda x: x == ['bb', 'cc']), 'trial_num']
```

Output:

```
1    2
Name: trial_num, dtype: int64
```

To only return the required value (`2`), simply append `.iloc[0]` to the end of the statement, as:

```
df.loc[df['samples'].apply(lambda x: x == ['bb', 'cc']), 'trial_num'].iloc[0]

>>> 2
```